# is it possible to do this with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, launcher, relaunch

first post. I have an interesting request that has to do with batch files.
I want to know if it's possible to code it so that the program that is launched with the bat file will terminate after a set amount of time, and then automatically restart, and then this just loops forever/until the program is exited.

anyone have any ideas?!

thanks!!

Comment: you're gonna have to explain what you mean by that....

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
:TOP
  START /b notepad.exe
  PING 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul
  TASKKILL /im notepad.exe
GOTO :TOP
```

The `/b` for `start` will fire up a command in the background.  We use `notepad.exe` in this example.

The strange `ping` command is a trick to get windows to sleep. `-n` takes a repeat count (5 in this case) and `-w` is the time in milisecs between pings.  So this will ping 5 times with 1 sec delay between.  in other words, it will wait for 5 secs.

Comment: thank you! i have one question before i attempt this. Where should i have the normal commands that are part of the batch file placed?

Comment: Ok the premise seems to work, yet I get the notice that I can't use that for taskkill and need to use /F to close forcefully. How do i add this?

Comment: taskkill /f /im notepad.exe if you want to force.  I did not include /f as you didn't provide any detail about what you're doing and /f could cause damage.  I have no idea what you mean by "normal commands".  Do you have a file you're trying to modify?  Please provide more details.